# How to use Reactive Extensions[RX] in Windows phone Application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, asynchronous, system.reactive

i'm Still looking for a better API for handling asynchronous requests  like synchronization operator in my Windows phone Project. well just take few minutes ,i have been found Reactive Extensions[RX] Framework.But i didn't know  how to use it .Can any one please suggest me some Suggestion how to learn the technique？

is there have some Step by Step demo 。i'm new guy for this .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The ReactiveUI EBook might be good for you, even if you're only interested in Rx itself, you can find it at http://www.reactiveui.net

Comment: FYI, the link goes to a network solutions domain parking page

Comment: Give it a minute, it's Being Weird™